# Accessing object property via variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like todo something like this.
**AppLocalizations.of(context)[i10nKey]**

I tried this but it throws error **(AppLocalizations.of(context) as Map)[i10nKey]**

> CastError (type 'AppLocalizationsEn' is not a subtype of type
> 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast)

ps: AppLocalizations is a built in flutter class for I10n

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Dart - dynamically get a property of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60853932/flutter-dart-dynamically-get-a-property-of-a-class)

Comment: @nvoigt it isn't. I cant change AppLocalizations as its a builtin class

Comment: You could make the method an [extension method](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods), so you don't need to change the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

add in your `AppLocalizations` class

```
String operator [](String key) => _localizedValues[key];
```

now you can use:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context)[i10nKey]
```