# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' : For both String and int

Tags: flutter, dart, subtype

I got the error for this code :

```
print(values["cont"]);
```

Upon which I tried this :

```
print(values["cont"].toString());
```

Here is `values` :

```
   values : {Contributions: 2, -Md0S2rcK4NSx0klfBoZ: {cont: Jharkhand Bokaro -Md0S2rZRI3S4QrP9lOi}, Rating: 5, name: Aadithya, City: Coimbatore, state: Tamil Nadu, -Md0S9MxN-jlXq4MoAl-: {cont: Karnataka Bagalkot -Md0S9MxN-jlXq4MoAkz}, email: aadi@gmail.com}
```

And once again, I get the same error. Please help

Comment: can you share full error and response?

Comment: try this. print(values["cont"] != null ? '$values["cont"]' : "Empty");

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the values array is expecting an integer as index.As per the error,

```
print(values["cont"]);
```

will throw an error but the below will not.

```
print(values[0]);
```

Please share how you have declared values array so that we can help

Comment: I'm sorry but it isn't an array. I have now editted it

Comment: if you are trying to get values from a class property, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60853932/flutter-dart-dynamically-get-a-property-of-a-class