# How to iterate using REST data?

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

```
for (var i=0; i<4; i++) GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => buildAirTicket(pdfurl: posts!.meta.flights.item0.flightticket),
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
          top: Radius.circular(12),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  child: AirTicketCard(
    aDate: DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(posts!.meta.flights.item0.flightDate),
    departureTime: posts!.meta.flights.item0.flightFromTime,
    arrivalTime: posts!.meta.flights.item0.flightToTime,
    departureCode: posts!.meta.flights.item0.flightFromCode,
    arrivalCode: posts!.meta.flights.item0.flightToCode,
    departureDestination: posts!.meta.flights.item0
        .flightFromLocation,
    arrivalDestination: posts!.meta.flights.item0
        .flightToLocation,
    flightcode: posts!.meta.flights.item0.flight,
  ),
),
```

So here is a for loop which will render "AirTicketCard" multiple times, 4 times in this case.
I want that with every iteration of for-loop from 0 to 4, the posts data example - "posts!.meta.flights.item0.flightDate" should also change from 0 to 4 in "item".

I tried doing "posts!.meta.flights.item${i}.flightDate" but its not working resulting in error.

Any possible fix?

Comment: is creating elif block a problem? you can change the item0 to item1 or item2 depending on the value of i

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Dart - dynamically get a property of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60853932/flutter-dart-dynamically-get-a-property-of-a-class)

Comment: Hi @RisheekMittal, can you explain more about this?

Comment: Just do a normal `for loop(){if(i==0){item0} elseif(i==1){item1}... and so on}` if you want an answer for this I can do that as well but I just want to understand what you want and what can be the most optimal solution for this.

Comment: @RisheeMittal, Thanks brother, it's working but I am trying something more dynamic so I don't have to hard code every time for i in if and else if.

Comment: is flights property an array?